# grow/shrink image gallery with jquery WITHOUT affecting the layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I got an image gallery organized as an `<ul>`. all images are in `<li>` elements and when I move my mouse over one of those pictures, it should grow to give the user a visual feedback. thing is, when I just change the size of the image using animate(), the other pictures will be pushed to the side as the resized image uses more space.

therefore I went with cloning the image element, float it right over the original image and then calling animate. this comes with the problem that onMouseOut() is called as soon as the cloned images pops up. so I need a nested hover() function and this is where things got complicated.

I got two errors and I can't find out whats causing them. the first one is, that animate() won't let the cloned image grow beyond the right border of its original, the second is, that I get weird grow/shrink behavior, when moving my mouse quickly over the gallery.

html:

```
<ul id="gallery1" class="gallery_container">
    <li class="frame">
    <a href=""><img src="pic1.jpg" class="picture" /></a></li><li class="frame">
    <a href=""><img src="pic2.jpg" class="picture" /></a></li><li class="frame">
    <a href=""><img src="pic3.jpg" class="picture" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
.picture
{
    height: 200px;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.frame
{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-right:8px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.frame a
{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
} 

.gallery_container
{
    height: 200px;
    width: 150%;
    position: relative;
    top: 4px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

and finally the code that is giving me those headaches:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
var zooming = false;
var zoom = 4;
var speed_zoom = 100;

$('.gallery_container li a').hover(function(element)
{
    // disable zooming to prevent unwanted behavior
    if(zooming) return;

    zooming = true;

    $(this).after( $(this).clone(false) );
    $(this).next().attr('id', 'focus_frame');
},
function(element) // when the new element pops up, onmouseout is triggered, since the focus_frame is in front of the image
{
    $(this).next().hover(function(element)
    {
        // we need to re-position the element in the dom-tree, since it needs to grow out of a container with overflow: hidden
        $('#focus_frame img').animate({'left' : zoom * -1, 'top' : zoom * -1, 'height' : 200+(zoom*2), 'width' : $('#focus_frame img').outerWidth() + (zoom*2)}, speed_zoom);
    },
    function(element)
    {
        $(this).remove();
        zooming = false;
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle?

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/y7gTb/1/) (updated) effect what you're after?

Comment: i did that  cloning the element being hovered for the don't change layout part, using css3 on that clone for the animate part

Comment: Bula: Yep - that's mostly it. But this is not an option, since it's not supported by IE :( Furthermore, the image has to grow from its center, not one of its edges...

Answer (score 1):

```
var $doc=$(document.body)
$doc.on({
"mouseenter" : function (e) {

    $doc.find("> .gallery_clone").remove();

    var $i=$(this).parent();
    $i.pos = $i.offset();
    $i.clone()
        .addClass("gallery_clone "+$i.parent().parent().attr("class"))
        .css({
            top:(Math.round($i.pos.top)-3)+"px"
            ,left:(Math.round($i.pos.left)-3)+"px"
            ,width:$i.width()
            }).appendTo($doc);

    }
},
  " ul > li > img"
).on ({

    "mouseleave" : function (e) {
       $(this).remove();
    },"> .gallery_clone");
```

in css `.gallery_clone` is `position:absolute`

then i animate `.gallery_clone:hover` through css but you can do it in the jquery as well i guess, adding a mouseenter event on .gallery_clone
edit : i've literally copy/pasted from my script so you'll have to adapt this code to your html

nb: give css anim a go, it's worth it even if older ie will not animate; (i also made lightbox effect almost pure css for that same gallery  - will publish later, not ready for plugin release just now sorry)

nb2: that part `"+$i.parent().parent().attr("class")` is because in the cms they can chose gallery background color so adding that class forward the background color & other gallery style to the clone (ie you should not need it)

Comment: so if i get your code correctly, you clone the li-element and position it absolutely on a complete new layer detached from the rest of the ul-li-stuff?

Comment: demo http://www.asercentre.org/?p=139 (check how it degrades in ie, i think it's not so bad - although i might have to add a couple of improvements)

Comment: @xenonite yah with the security that this element gets removed if not hovered

Comment: seems to be a good start, but i have some problems. I'll post my final solution here one i've succeeded. thanks so far!